# Plotting a 3D surface or volume, given x, y and z intervals

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I plot a volume described by the following intervals?

```
3<x<5
0<z<x
0<y<x^2
```

I've tried to generate two sets of vectors. One describing the start point and one describing an end point between which the surface should be.

```
%start vectors
x1=3:0.1:5;
y1=zeros(21, 1);
z1=zeros(21, 1);

%end vectors
x2=x1;
y2=x1.^2;
z2=x1;

hold on

%plot the points in the same figure
scatter3(x2,y2,z2);
scatter3(x1,y1,z1);

hold off
```

However my attempt only displays each point and I'm unsure if they're even correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your question isn't very clear, but I suppose you want something like this?

```
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(3:0.1:5,3:0.1:5);
surf(xx,yy,xx.^2);
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('z');
```

Comment: The three intervals describe how each axis of a shape changes. In my understanding, it's a shape between x=3 and x=5. Its height is the square of the current x value giving it a slope. Its depth changes as well, from 0 to x. From what I can see by the plot you describe, there's no change in z. Shouldn't its depth grow larger as well?

Comment: z does change, the value 3:0.1:5 is a small difference, if you try 3:0.5:15 you will see the slope better.